# How to properly calculate the medium in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data table like this:
[image]

As you can see my data table has multiple companies that I want to aggregate. It all works fine but on `CPL` field I have the already calculated medium (`cost/leads`).

Whenever I try to add `CPL` to the Metrics, my data becomes a "mess" because it shows me the `SUM` of all `CPL` values for the same company or the `AVG` of the (Number of times the company name appears / SUM of CPL).

I've tried to do this multiple times including the calculated fields but wasn't able to make this work fine.

I've also tried adding `CPL` as a dimension but it splits the `Account Name` just like my datasheet making the data view useless.

At this point, I need to show the `CPL` from each company. Considering I have thousands of lines.

Is there a way to add `CPL` as a metric or dimension without losing the data aggregation?

I've also gave a try to this on Excel Pivot Tables, but the result was the same as shown on Google Data Studio:

[image: excel pivot table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create the `CPL` field in Google Data Studio by [aggregating](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9320174) each field using the [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) function:

```
SUM(Cost) / SUM(Leads)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3fe11ca4-6e17-4642-a05c-a0ed1cc59568) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iE9EGMZTXf7UD84Wu4gmWvLbryqedMyByb-5FP8ARJg/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]